# Koolwired.Imap - How do I delete messages?

Tags: c#, imap

I'm trying to delete all the emails from a mailbox using the Koolwired.Imap library. I have the following code that should be marking all the messages and they, once all are marked, delete them,

```
        _mailbox = _command.Fetch(_mailbox);
        foreach (ImapMailboxMessage m in _mailbox.Messages)
        {
            try
            {
                _command.SetDeleted(m.ID, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Marking Error: " + e.Message + "(" + m.MessageID + ")");
            }
        }
        try
        {
            _command.Expunge();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expunge Error: " + e.Message);
        }
```

When I run the above code i get the following errors:

```
Marking Error: Input string was not in a correct format.()
Marking Error: No UID found for message number3()
Marking Error: No UID found for message number1()
Marking Error: Input string was not in a correct format.()
Marking Error: Input string was not in a correct format.()
Marking Error: Input string was not in a correct format.()
```

I looks like there is an issue with the message UID on most of the message. After this runs about 99% of the messages are not deleted, some 2-3 are deleted. If I re-run the program, i get the same errors but a few less and another 2-3 emails are deleted.

How am I supposed to delete emails with the Koolwired.Imap library?
Are there other Imap libraries that work with c#? When i was looking this is the only one that I found.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it should work according to http://imapnet.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=73377 and I see you posted out there as well.  Have you tried setting up a gmail account and testing it against that just to see what happens?

As for other libraries, I have used the EAGetMail POP3 & IMAP4 component (cannot add link due to my new account: www.emailarchitect.net/eagetmail/)   on previous projects and had good luck with it.

Comment: I am testing this code with a gmail account. I'll take a look at the lib you've listed.